# Changing keyboard keys on new Ubuntu 18.04, xmodmap not working any more?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

I have upgraded my ubuntu to the latest 18.04 version and now my manual set shortcuts for some symbols on the keyboard are not working any more.

Usually I was doing it by executing the following command:

```
 xmodmap -e "keycode  15 = 6 ampersand 6 asciicircum bar fiveeighths"
```

But after the upgrade, this doesn't work any more. By pressing alt+key 6 I am not getting the "and" sign as I should.

Is xmodmap not available any more? Is there some other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed. Xmodmap is no longer supported in gnome.
Pleas install gnome tweak tools where you could adjust your keyboard mapping in a gui.

Comment: unfortunately the GUI doesn't give the flexibility that xmodmap gives/gave (say, mapping PrtSc to Ctrl)